# Preview 10.1 in macOS Mojave does not capture signature with camera

Tags: preview, camera, signature

I recently bought a MacBook Air and I am not being able to capture a signature in a white sheet of paper with camera, as it was possible in previous machines and mac OS versions.
Does someone have a hint on how to solve this?

Answer (score 14):

When you select the camera on the Preview.app, It should open the camera up. You need keep some distance between the FaceTime camera and the white paper only then Preview.app will pick it up.

- If it's kept too close, the signature will not be picked up.
- keep the paper stable as the camera will not detect if the paper wobbles around.
- Place a light behind the camera shining towards the paper if needed. Strong contrast helps the signature detection.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It was not working with me in the beginning, but the problem solved when I had a spot light points in parallel between the laptop screen and the paper. Max light is needed apparently.

Answer (score 1):

As other have mentioned in the comments, it really seems to need a lot of light on the paper (probably so it can see the contrast). Much more than you would normally need for doing FaceTime call for example.

Place a strong light source behind your MacBook/webcam (e.g. room light, window, or flashlight) so that its light falls strongly on the paper with the signature. Then slowly move the paper towards the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you can try is to take a colored paper and use a different kind of pencil.
For me it was very easy using a beige one, which got recognized immediately